# Appending rows from two separate pandas dataframes onto one dataframe based on certain conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append

I have two dataframes, and each row in dataframe1 (df1) could potentially match to a row in dataframe2 (df2). So I want to create a final dataframe that appends each row of df1, and under each row, rows from df2 that have matching cells. The goal is to find how many rows in df1 have candidates in df2 based on matching columns. Here is how it should look:

dataframe1

[image: 1]

dataframe2

[image: 2]

final dataframe

[image: final]

Here is the code I produced. It works well, but it is just far too slow:

```
for i, y in df1.iterrows():
    final = final.append(df1.loc[i])
    final = final.append(df2.loc[

        (df2.column1 == df2.loc[i, "column1"]) | 
        (df2.column2 == df2.loc[i, "column2"]) 

     ], sort = True)
```

I was wondering if there was a faster way to append rows from the two dataframes to a final one. Thank you for any help, it is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps,

```
df_merged = pd.merge(df1,df2,how='inner',left_on=['Number'],right_on=['Number']) #merging both dataframes together
len(df_merged) #getting number of observations in the merged dataset
```

Comment: This code that you wrote just merges the dataframes, I'm looking for something that matches rows in the second frame to rows in the first with similar information in columns

Comment: try using pd.concat and then by removing duplicated rows from the merged dataframe